# How to create an RDD that has data type of string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this line of code:

```
<scala> val quoteRDD = sc.parallelize("\"")
quoteRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Char] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize
```

How can have this RDD that holds the "\"" as a string data type?  Spark says its a char, but I am  needing a string data type.

Can you help me with this change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparkContext.parallelize` has following signature

```
def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]
```

and `String` can be substituted ([with implicit conversions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/strings.html)) for `Seq[Char]`.

If you really want to create single element `RDD[String]` (not much use for that, but let's call it an exercise) add `Seq` wrapper:

```
val quoteRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("\""))
```